# What kind of conflict(s) can happen with updateWithOnConflict()?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I understand *inserting* a row can cause a conflict if the row is a duplicate, but what kind of conflicts can an update cause? I can't think of any.

In other words, what is `updateWithOnConflict()` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs:

`The ON CONFLICT clause applies to UNIQUE, NOT NULL, CHECK, and PRIMARY KEY constraints`

If you update something it will fail if it you have a `UNIQUE` requirement but the update makes it no longer unique, or if you try to update a `NOT NULL` field with null.  You can also have multiple primary keys on a table, and should never change those.

It also depends on how you are using it.  Maybe you want your app to throw an exception so you can catch it and log it somewhere, or maybe you don't care and just want to use the `CONFLICT_REPLACE` flag so you don't have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Conflicts can arise from many constraints: primary key, unique, foreign key (if enabled), etc.

Imagine a user trying to update a row's `_id` to an existing one. This would create a duplicate row `_id` which would lead to the same conflict as your inserting example.

[image: SQLite Column Constraint Diagram]

Just in case, update conflicts aren't just localized to Android's implementation of SQLite, [it's fundamental to SQLite itself](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) but you probably know this.

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, what is `updateWithOnConflict()` for?

The main difference between `update` and `updateWithOnConflict` is that the latter will allow actions to be taken if a conflict occurs (e.g. a constraint is violated), whilst the former will result in an exception (which could be trapped).

In short it provides a greater degree of control when a constraint is violated. However, you can also utilise a [conflict-clause](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/conflict-clause.html) to very much do the same (although the conflict-clause doesn't provide the flexibility of being easily changed dynamically).

For example assume a table defined with :-

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,           // IMPLIED CONSTRAINT UNIQUE NOT NULL
    thing_name TEXT UNIQUE,            // COLUMN CONSTRAINT UNIQUE
    table2_reference INTEGER NOT NULL, // COLUMN CONSTRAINT NOT NULL
    table3_reference INTEGER NOT NULL, // as previous
    CONSTRAINT table2_to_table3 UNIQUE // TABLE CONSTRAINT UNIQUE
        (table2_reference, table3_reference)
);
```

And populated with :-

[image]

And we have an update method, that caters for using both update and updateWithOnConflict such as :-

```
public void updateRow(
        long id,
        String newname,
        long newtable2ref,
        long newtable3ref,
        boolean with_on_conflict_flag) {
    if (id < 1) return;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    if (newname != null && newname.length() > 0 ) {
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_THINGNAME,newname);
    }
    if (newtable2ref > 0) {
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_TBL2REF,newtable2ref);
    }
    if (newtable3ref > 0) {
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_TBL3REF,newtable3ref);
    }
    if (cv.size() > 0) {
        if (with_on_conflict_flag) {
            mDB.updateWithOnConflict(
                    TB_MYTABLE,cv,
                    COL_MYTABLE_ID + "=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE //<<<< IGNORE exception
            );
        } else {
            mDB.update(
                    TB_MYTABLE,
                    cv, COL_MYTABLE_ID + "=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}
                    );
        }
    }
}
```

and then **`mDBHlpr.updateRow(1,null,1,2,????);`** is used twice

- first with ???? as **false**
- and then with **true**
- i.e. a constraint violation is being forced as this would attempt to create a non-unique combination (*the combination of table2_reference and table3_reference would match the 2nd row*).

The first where just the update method is invoked would result in an exception and the App would stop e.g. :-

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: columns table2_reference, table3_reference are not unique (code 19)
```

The second traps the error ignoring it (as per the conflict-algorithm), so doing nothing *(although the log will contain the stack trace for the error)*.

Note the action by the `updateWithOnConflict` method is dependent upon the 5th parameter (CONFLICT_IGNORE was used in the above). here's a list of the conflict-algorithms  as er [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html):-

> **CONFLICT_ABORT**
>
> When a constraint violation occurs,no ROLLBACK is executed so changes
>   from prior commands within the same transaction are preserved.
>
> **CONFLICT_FAIL**
>
> When a constraint violation occurs, the command aborts with a return
>   code SQLITE_CONSTRAINT.
>
> **CONFLICT_IGNORE**
>
> When a constraint violation occurs, the one row that contains the
>   constraint violation is not inserted or changed.
>
> **CONFLICT_NONE**
>
> Use the following when no conflict action is specified.
>
> **CONFLICT_REPLACE**
>
> When a UNIQUE constraint violation occurs, the pre-existing rows that
>   are causing the constraint violation are removed prior to inserting or
>   updating the current row.
>
> **CONFLICT_ROLLBACK**
>
> When a constraint violation occurs, an immediate ROLLBACK occurs, thus
>   ending the current transaction, and the command aborts with a return
>   code of SQLITE_CONSTRAINT.